# Unlist all items from quanteda tokens object into data frame

Tags: r, quanteda

```
library(quanteda)
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), text = c("I am loving it", "I am hating it but I go, and I teach"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

myDfm <- df$text %>%
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE) %>%
  tokens_remove(pattern = c(stopwords(source = "smart")))
```

How is it possible to unlist the data frame and have this format

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2), text = c("loving", "hating teach")
```

I tried to unlist it using this:

```
unlist(myDfm$text[1:length(myDfm)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text data can be extracted as follows.

```
library(quanteda)
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), text = c("I am loving it", "I am hating it but I go"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

myDfm <- df$text %>%
     tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE) %>%
     tokens_remove(pattern = c(stopwords(source = "smart")))

data.frame(id = 1:length(myDfm),text = unlist(myDfm))
```

...and the output:

```
> data.frame(id = 1:length(myDfm),text = unlist(myDfm))
      id   text
text1  1 loving
text2  2 hating
>
```

Comment: Thank you. How is it possible to use this option data.frame(id = df$id,text = unlist(myDfm)) without receiving an error like this `Error in data.frame(id = df$id, text = unlist(myDfm)) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 3`

Comment: @Nathalie - what happens if you print `df$id` right before the `data.frame()` function? How many elements does it contain? The error message indicates that `df$id` has 3 elements. If I add `data.frame(id = df$id,text = unlist(myDfm))` as the next line of code in my R script, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

```r
data.frame(
  id = seq_along(myDfm),
  text = sapply(myDfm, paste, collapse = " "),
  row.names = NULL
)
##   id         text
## 1  1       loving
## 2  2 hating teach
```

Note that your `myDfm` is a tokens object, not a dfm.